# Angular 2 how to send events from grandchild to parent component?

Tags: events, angular

I have a **GridComponent** inside a **PopupComponent**.

I want to send an "RowSelected" custom event to a component **outside of PopupComponent**.

I am currently sending the event from GridComponent to PopupComponent and forwarding it to the outside. This is an very painful approach since I plan on having tons of PopupComponents.

Is there any other way to do event forwarding?

Comment: Use a service with a Subject, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Do you know if different **GridComponent**s (ex. one contains people and the other contains jobs) will share the same service?
That would be unfortunate for me.

Comment: Each GridComponent can have its own instance of some service.  In addition, you can also have a single instance of some other OutsideService for some collection of GridComponents.

Comment: I asked this question in reddit.com/r/angular2 a while ago too. One of the recommended way is using Observable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Whenever you don't have a direct parent → child relationship, use a (shared) service to share data and/or send events.

Inside the service, use a Subject or an Observable to accomplish this.

The [cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) has an example of how to use a Subject to achieve bi-directional communication between components.

This SO post, [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2), has an example of how to use an Observable.

Comment: Thank you! Everything works nicely when there is a parent=>grandchild, but when the "grandchild" is alone in the context of the application, it tells: 
 `No provider for service (grandchild -> service)`

Comment: @LukaŠilje, it sounds like you do not have a service defined (using `providers`) high enough up in your hierarchy of components.  I suggest you take a look at the [Hierarchical Injectors doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html).

Comment: Hello again. It was working until I converted to release (2.0.0). Any idea?
I am injecting the service into providers of the AppComponent.

Comment: It seems they don't have the same service. I used the BehaviorSubject to see the value and it is always null in one component and not null in the other.

Comment: @LukaŠilje, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-root-component-or-module -- provide your service in the AppModule rather than in AppComponent.

Comment: Thank you! It really solved my problem. In every component that used the common service I had "providers:[thatCommonService]" instead of declaring it only in one place (module). I am not used to the module thing yet.